# API for getting data from a disease name?

Tags: openfda, uses-of-open-data, disease

For example, entering: "lung Adenocarcinoma" should return (JSON preferably) large chunks of information about that disease, such as definition, alternate names, validity, treatments, signs, etc..

I've tried using the [seer](https://api.seer.cancer.gov) API. but I run into an issue trying to get the correct disease identifier. If I try inputting "lung Adenocarcinoma" into the disease search endpoint, I get no results.

```
{
terms: [
"lung adenocarcinoma"
],
total: 0,
count: 25,
order: "score"
}
```

Comment: What type of data are you looking for? It sounds like you want information that could be provided from MedlinePlus, Wikipedia, and/or WikiData. Potentially RxMix or UMLS if you are looking for treatment information. I dont think `healthcare-finder-api` nor `openfda` will have what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe there is something related to ATC codes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_Therapeutic_Chemical_Classification_System

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried a Wolfram Alpha search. There is a lot of information there.

[Wolfram|Alpha: lung adenocarcinoma](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lung%20adenocarcinoma)

You can get this information in Mathematica as well for analysis by using the [`WolframAlpha` function](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha.html).

This gets you the same formatted output in Mathematica as shown on the WolframAlpha site.

```
WolframAlpha["lung adenocarcinoma"]
```

If you just need computable data (the data underlying the formatted data then this will return it.

```
KeySelect[#[[2]] == "ComputableData" &]@WolframAlpha["lung adenocarcinoma", "DataRules"]
```

[image]

In Mathematica, you could also use the ["Disease" Interpreter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/Disease.html) or the ["ComputedDisease" Interpreter](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/ComputedDisease.html) to get information.

```
d = Interpreter["Disease"]["lung adenocarcinoma"];
props = EntityValue[d, d["Properties"], "PropertyAssociation"];
Grid[KeyValueMap[{CanonicalName@#1, #2} &]@props, Alignment -> Left]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.